# How to connect to an API (documentation is a bit high level): aqua.io

Tags: node.js

Being quite new to javascript I have trouble making sense out of this documentation: https://github.com/Aquaio/aqua-io-node-js

especially the clientOptions are not clear to me (how to format them?):

```
var client = aquaIo.client({
client_id: '09a8b7',
client_secret: '1a2b3'
}, clientOptions);
```

I am not sure, how to format the options. I tried it this way: https://gist.github.com/perler/3c8dbc74e16582dbfbd5d1a6ca85a8fd but this throws errors like

```
/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/aqua-io/lib/aqua_io/api/access_token.js:21                                                                                                   
var body = (options['body'] ? options['body'] : {});   
TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined
```

The goal is to simply get an entry from the DB in JSON to parse it later on.

Comment: Have you registered and generated the client id and secret? Once you get the id and secret , you need to provide those while creating client.

Comment: sure, I just blanked them out for the example.